# junk characters coming when i export Azure Databricks(ADB) table data in excel

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

When i see my table data in azure databricks , data looks fine.

But when i Export the same data in Excel , i can see some junk characters coming

**in databricks -**
23/5 DELHI - MATHURA

**in excel -**
23/5 **Â** DELHI - MATHURA

how to make sure that junk character -> **Â** does not come in excel , i want to do change on databricks side , not on excel side , as excel is just displaying the data.

Comment: Could you please share the same data to test the scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this myself . thing is in spark junk characters are not visible in the output window , but when i download excel , i could see junk characters in them.

since i was getting a junk character at a position where there was empty space visible , so i copied that space and put it in notepad++/google , to check its unicode value , i was able to found the unicode value .

then in source file from where table is getting populated , i replaced that unicode value in whole file